# How can pi be calculated to a set number of digits in PHP?

Tags: php, math, pi

How can I calculate the value of pi in PHP up to X decimal numbers.

**4 decimal points**

> 3.141

**64 decimal points**

> 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592

Comment: the main problem is calculating value of pi upto 100000 decimal numbers...

Comment: Nit picky, but the `3` is not in a decimal position (a digit position after the decimal point, `.`), so those numbers only have 3 and 63 decimal digits, respectively.

Answer (score 4):

Found the source for the broken link @Konamiman posted.

Compared the results to: http://www.angio.net/pi/digits/50.txt and they are the same.

```
// Source: http://mgccl.com/2007/01/22/php-calculate-pi-revisited
function bcfact($n)
{
    return ($n == 0 || $n== 1) ? 1 : bcmul($n,bcfact($n-1));
}
function bcpi($precision)
{
    $num = 0;$k = 0;
    bcscale($precision+3);
    $limit = ($precision+3)/14;
    while($k < $limit)
    {
        $num = bcadd($num, bcdiv(bcmul(bcadd('13591409',bcmul('545140134', $k)),bcmul(bcpow(-1, $k), bcfact(6*$k))),bcmul(bcmul(bcpow('640320',3*$k+1),bcsqrt('640320')), bcmul(bcfact(3*$k), bcpow(bcfact($k),3)))));
        ++$k;
    }
    return bcdiv(1,(bcmul(12,($num))),$precision);
}

echo bcpi(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating PI in php?

Why calculate when we already have the `M_PI` constant?

`M_PI` contains the value `3.14159265358979323846`.

10000 decimal places for PI is quite a number.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php

Comment: Apparently you can set the precision of `pi()`/`M_PI` in php.ini. Not sure if it goes to 11^H 100K though. :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.pi.php

Comment: Too bad, apparently it only goes to 48, on my system at least. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate Pi by the Chudnosky series. If you have a server with a very high ram you can easily calculate Pi to many decimal places. If you want to get it to some specific decimal place then, increase the efforts to a really large number and use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to shorten it to your required decimal place. If you think this process is very slow, then you can get pi value by searching it on google.

Comment: This is a very slow way to do it as the series converges slowly.

Comment: @Salixalba Can you see, I have written there '...a server with a very high ram...'.

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80 Calculating π to 10 correct decimal places using direct summation of the series requires about 5,000,000,000 terms. Throwing more ram at the problem won't help much better to try a different formula like those at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Answer (score -4):

PHP cannot hold a number that long as far as I know, but 22/7 is an ancient way to calculate PI, though that will not be any better than the PI constant included in PHP.  Perhaps you are trying to output a long string of PI as an exercise.

Comment: 22/7 is hardly accurate; the native PHP constant is at least accurate to the precision possible on a given system.