# Finding the expansion of PI

Tags: java, php, javascript, c++, .net

In an interview, I was asked to find a first 9 digit palindrome in an expansion of PI. And I had no idea as to how I should go for it. The question remained in my system throughout the interview and I couldn't properly answer the questions to follow.

Whats the optimal way?

EDIT:

Finding palindrome is not difficult but how can I get the expansion of PI as much as I need. I have tried Math.PI, i have tried 22/7 but nothing gives me what I need.

Comment: What do you mean by expansion of PI? A mathematical series summing to PI?

Comment: did you need to tag this with so many languages?

Comment: @beanland: getting the expansion of PI is a problem, not finding the palindrome.

Comment: @dagon: I need it in any of the language. Because language does not matter here.

Comment: well how you do it, very much will depend on which language you do it in.

Comment: So the question you really want an answer to is how to perform an expansion of pi to an arbitrary precision?  The palindrome part of the question is a red herring (you aren't really interested in that bit).

Comment: Found this for php: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10370315/1377507

Answer (score 2):

the "optimal" way here strongly depends on the choice of the algorithm for calculating Pi, assuming you don't have access to an arbitrary number of digits off the shelf.

There are lots of infinite sums that converge against pi, each of which capable of eventually producing the right digits, however you'd have to use some library that allows infinitely precise floating point numbers, or infinitely large integers.

After that, finding the palindromes is relatively easy, as you'd only have to compare the first to the ninth number, the second to the eighth and so forth.

The devil in this case is clearly which converging sum to use for the approximation of Pi.
A couple of these are listed on the wikipedia page for Pi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Polygon_approximation_era

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would make a subset of the numbers in pi and convert to a string.

I would take a nine character subset string from it, then compare the first character with the last one. If they match, compare character 2 with 8 and so on. If any of the comparisons fails then move the 9 character string to the next set - by one character.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably point the assign the `first index` value to `first variable` and `ninth index` value to `second variable` and then see if they are equal . In case they are equal I will assign `second index` value to `first variable` and `eight index` value to `second variable` till they meet at mid postion . In case they differ with one another at some place assign `first variable` the value of the `latest left side index` which differs with `right side index` and second variable value of the `left side index + 8` and repeat process till you reach `last index - 8` position .